# Why is this definition of an injective function incorrect?

Tags: functions, definition

Consider the following definition:
$$
\mathrm{function\ } f(x) \mathrm{\ is \ injective} \iff \forall_{a \in D_f} \forall_{b \in D_f} \left( a \neq b  \land f(a) \neq f(b) \right)
$$

Seems sound to me. But, if we negate it, we get this nonesense:
$$
\mathrm{function\ } f(x) \mathrm{\ is \ not \ injective } \iff \exists_{a \in D_f} \exists_{b \in D_f} \left( a = b  \lor f(a) = f(b) \right)
$$

We can conclude that this definition is rubbish. However, this isn't evident at a glance, I cannot see that this definition is invalid without performing the negation trick. Could anyone explain this to me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\forall_{a \in D_f} \forall_{b \in D_f} \left( a \neq b  \land f(a) \neq f(b) \right)$ implies that $\forall_{a \in D_f} \forall_{b \in D_f} \left( a \neq b\right),$ i.e. if you take any $a,b\in D_f$ then these are different. But when you take $a$ you don't remove it from $D_f$; it's still there, so $b$ can be the same element. Then $a \neq b$ is absurd.

Comment: Clear and concise explanation!

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the first definition should be$$f\text{ injective}\iff(\forall a\in D_f)(\exists b\in D_f):a\ne b\implies f(a)\ne f(b).$$Its negation is$$f\text{ not injective}\iff(\exists a\in D_f)(\exists b\in D_f):a\ne b\wedge f(a)=f(b)$$and that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

The condition should be
$$
\forall_{a\in D_f}\,\forall_{b\in D_f}(a\ne b\to f(a)\ne f(b))
$$
which is very different from the one stated in your question.

You need to express the condition “*if $a\ne b$, then $f(a)\ne f(b)$*”. It's a common error to state this improperly as “*$a\ne b$ and $f(a)\ne f(b)$*”, but as you see from the negation it is nonsense.

By the way, the statement with $(a\ne b\land f(a)\ne f(b))$ is false unless the domain of $f$ is empty.